# Difference between variable declaration and definition in C. When does the memory gets allocated?

Tags: c, variables, memory-management, definition, variable-declaration

So I have been trying to learn C on my own. So just a couple of videos and articles and a a book by my side. Although it sounds like a simple concept (I'm sure it is), I dnt think the concept is clear to me.

Can you please quote an example when a variable is ***declared*** or ***defined***?(together and separately)

Like in some articles or forums I read they say

***Int x; ( x is declared)***

Somewhere it's written

***Int x; ( x is defined).***

When will the ***memory be allocated*** to the variable?
Again somewhere it is said that variable has to be defined first to get memory allocated and somewhere it's said it is allocated when a variable is declared?

Comment: `int x;` is always a definition

Comment: Basically ... *declare*: tell the compiler the variable exists and has a defined type, eg: `int foobar;`. The linker will find out **where** it exists. *define* tell the compiler the variable exists **here** and has the specific value, eg: `int foobar = -42;`

Comment: @pmg your two cases are both definitions; one has an initializer  (providing an initial value makes no difference to the storage class or whatever)

Comment: Right, first one is a "tentative definition" though :)

Comment: @M.M if int x; is a definition, can u quote an example for declaration please?

Comment: @pmg I'm afraid I don't know what a tentative definition is.

Comment: When applied to functions, a definition has code (between `{` and `}`), a declaration does not... `int declaration(const char *p);` vs `int definition(const char *p) { return *p - '0'; }`

Comment: `extern int x;`

Comment: For reference: [C11, htmlized draft](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) and [C2x PDF draft from WG14](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2478.pdf)

Comment: Many at forums mix up the words, so please be careful. If you want certainty, you need to read the standard. Many C books are of doubtful quality when it comes to these issues.

Comment: @bolov....thanks a lot...great answer...yes it answered my question :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Like in some articles or forums I read they say
> Int x; ( x is declared)
> Somewhere it's written
> Int x; ( x is defined).

Actually the `int x;` declares and defines it at the same time so both are valid but incomplete.

The declaration shows the compiler the type of variable without creating it.

```
extern int x; // <- this is declaration
```

Definition creates the the object, if the object was declared before its definition must match the declaration.

```
extern int x;
int x;
```

Is valid but

```
extern int x;
double x;
```

is not.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this give you a small overview about when variables become declared, allocated, initialized, deallocated and vanished (destroyed).

```
/* global variable A declared and memory for int is allocated */
/* memory will only be unallocated at global program exit */
/* global variable A initialized/defined with value 10 */
int A = 10;

void test(int D){
    /* function test is called by main with argument test(5) */
    /* local variable D is declared, memory for int is allocated */
    /* and initialized with value 5 */
    
    /* add local variable D to global variable A */
    A = A + D;
    
    /* after this point, local variable D will be deallocated */
    /* and will vanish */
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    /* local variable B declared, memory for int allocated */
    /* and initialized with value 20 */
    int B = 20;
    
    {
        /* local scoped variable C declared, memory for int allocated */
        /* and initialized with value 30 */
        int C = 30;
        /* after this point, local scoped variable C will be */
        /* deallocated and will vanish */
    }
    
    /* 5 is a local scoped const of size int, memory will be allocated */
    test(5);
    /* after this point, local scoped const 5 will be deallocated */
    /* and will vanish */
    
    
    /* after this point, local variable B will be deallocated */
    /* and will vanish */
    return A;
}
```

Comment: You make it seem like the program source code is processed sequentilally in chronological order, including lines outside of functions. I consider this misleading. Using the expression "allocate" for a global variable is questionable. The effect of settingup/preparing memory for global variables is done at load time, according to information determined by the linking phase, which takes place after compilation. (Downvote not by me however.)

Comment: global variables will be declared/allocated and initialized before main(). So using this order is the right way.

Comment: @paladin not the DV but you are totally wrong, _global variables will be declared/allocated and initialized before main()_  that's not how the compiler works, allocated is a wrong term, do you mean filled?

Comment: You are both right, but I wanted to keep it simple. Memory management is much more complicated than shown in my example. But I hope this gives OP an idea how it might work.

Comment: _but I wanted to keep it simple_, and this is good, but allocated/deallocated is very confusing, the process of destroying local objects is called "stack unwinding", consider "stacked up" for allocated.